# Fourier transform of angular part of function in spherical coordinates.

Tags: integral-transforms

This is the maths part of a physics problem - that of the solution of Schrodinger equation for a 3D harmonic oscillator in spherical coordinates. The solution is a product of associated Laguerre functions multiplied with Gaussians (this much for the radial part), multiplied with the spherical harmonics, since the Hamiltonian has spherical symmetry. The problem is, I am supposed to normalize them in momentum space, using the condition:

$N^2 \int d^3k \ \psi^* \psi = (2\pi)^3$. 
where \psi is the momentum space wavefunction, in 3D, and N is the norm. 
Now, the radial part of the integral is not very hard to evaluate, but I have no experience with solution of the angular part. I mean, first, how do I get the FT of spherical harmonics, and second, solve this integral to arrive at the norm?

Maybe, my troubles originate from the fact that while I have some experience with FT's of the kind encountered in e.g. the radial part, I have never encountered the FT of spherical harmonics before. So, I would be extremely grateful if someone recommends me a basic text in case my question appears trivial.

PS - I know some of the suggestions would be to solve this equation right away in momentum space. But I have been asked to do it in this brute force manner first, before I start looking at alternatives.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Fourier Transforms of Spherical Harmonics in real space are (up to trivial factors) Spherical Harmonics in momentum space, see for example eq. (3.15) in http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/qua.10085
or eq. (34) of the article in http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2008BaltA..17..383M